# No package available when installing packages on CentOS 6.6

Tags: linux, centos, mysql, yum, centos-6

I wanted to install `mysql-server` on CentOS 6.6 (64bit). When I run `yum install mysql-server`, I get the following error:

```
root@ip-50-62[/home/syn]# yum install mysql-server
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: p3plmirror02.prod.phx3.secureserver.net
 * extras: p3plmirror02.prod.phx3.secureserver.net
 * jpackage-generic: ftp.heanet.ie
 * jpackage-generic-updates: ftp.heanet.ie
 * rpmforge: mirror.hmc.edu
 * updates: p3plmirror02.prod.phx3.secureserver.net
No package mysql-server available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

How do I install it?

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem myself. File `/etc/yum.com` had `mysql*` excluded. I removed `mysql*` for some period of time & installed it. I got installed like a charm. Now putting back the `mysql*` in exclude.

Hope that helps someone!

Comment: What is `/etc/yum.com` means ? It is `/etc/yum.conf` right ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that MySQL is no longer a part of the repo in CentOS 7, but you are using CentOS 6.6. If you want to go down the MariaDB route, many online postings—like [this one at Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/can-t-install-mysql-on-centos-7)—point to using MariaDB as a drop-in substitute for MySQL and recommend just installing MariaDB instead via this command:

```
sudo yum install mariadb-server mariadb
```

But doing some more searching shows that MySQL can still be installed via this command as explained [in this posting on installing MySQL 5.6 Fedora, CentOS and RedHat](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-mysql-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/):

```
sudo yum install mysql-community-server
```

One thing you can always do with [`yum` is search the repository](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/s1-yum-useful-commands.html) for packages that have a certain name or contain certain words like this:

```
yum search mysql*
```

Which should give you a list of any/all packages in the repository that contain that word in it.